# htacess redirect subsomains to root domain and force www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have an annoying issue that I am trying to redirect all subdomains to root domain and force www. At the moment it forces www as needed but if I go to sub.example.dom I am able to and this is what I am trying to prevent. Here is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^service-description/([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /location.php?city=$1&process=$2 [L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct approach is to add another rewriting rule that redirects all requests to host names *not* starting with `www`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

You can actually simplify this *if* your http server does *not* answer to other second level domains or if you want to redirect *all* requests regardless of which host name they target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Those rule sets will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and in case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).